# Simplifying an equation with a derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dt}t + y \implies \frac{d}{dt}[ty]$

Why is the above true?

I can't figure out this step when solving a basic, introductory differential equation (learning about integrating factors). This appears to be the step I am missing, I just don't know why that implication is true.

Comment: Recall the product rule for differentiation.

Comment: do you know the rule for derivative of a product ($ty$)?

Comment: no, i havent done calculus in over a decade really.

Comment: Because $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ And the derivative of t wrt t is $1$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}[ty] = \frac{d}{dt}[t] \cdot y + t \cdot \frac{d}{dt}[y] = y +  t \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} $

Comment: @stevengregory thanks! that makes sense. can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are two rules here
The derivative of a product pf two functions is:
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$
$$\implies (ty(t))'=(t)'y(t)+t(y(t))'$$
And another rule
$$\frac {dt^n}{dt}=nt^{n-1}$$
$$\implies (t)'=1t^0=1$$
The result follows
$$(ty(t))'=y(t)+ty'(t)$$
Or if you prefer another notation:
$$\frac {d(ty(t))}{dt}=y(t)+t\frac {dy(t)}{dt}$$